# Can a flowlet pass through all columns?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory and are exploring if we could use Flowlets for transformations that occur in most Data flows.

Our first attempt was to create a flowlets that only add some columns (using a "Derived Column" step) to a stream. So in the "Input" step we don't require any column to be present in the received stream. Then the "Derived Column" followed by the "Output" step. And done... we thought.

When using this flowlet in a data flow we go from 25 columns back to only the column we added, all our original columns are no longer available.

Is it possible to use a flowlet to work on only a selection of all available columns but that all columns in the stream are "passed through" and thus will be available in the sink of the original data flow?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to select the Allow Schema Drift option on your Flowlet input settings

[image]